# React onClientClick not firing my function handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, event-handling

I have a button component, lets call it < MyButton >.

```js
<MyButton
  onClick={this.props.calculate}
  onClientClick={this.changeColor}
>
   Calculate
</MyButton>
```

When I click the button my `calculate` function fires. It's an arrow function that lives in the parent component class, and takes an event as a parameter, like `calculate = (event) =>{...}`

But when I click the button, the `changeColor` function does not fire. It's also an arrow function, but it lives in the component class that I'm working in. Altogether, with my button code, it looks like this

```js
class Toolbar extends Component {

    // a bunch of functions
  
   changeColor = (event) =>{
        console.log("here")
   }

   // more code
   <MyButton onClick={this.props.calculate} onClientClick={this.changeColor}>
      Calculate
   </MyButton>

}
```

Why is my `changeColor` function not working, when I structured it like the `calculate` function?

Oddly enough, when I swap out the `this.changeColor` for a `console.log()` like `onClientclick={console.log("hello")}` it dumps "hello" in the console. But not when I try to console log through the function itself.

Comment: Please show where `MyButton` uses the `onClientClick` prop. `onClientclick={console.log("hello")}` because the console log is executed immediately and not in response to any user interactions.

Comment: @DrewReese makes sense why the console logs fire on page reload, but they also fire on click.

Comment: you need to share `MyButton` implementation, otherwise your question cannot be answered properly

Comment: @buzatto `MyButton` is a wrapper around a standard html `button`. There is no implementation beyond the styling defined in the component class. I was under the impression onClientClick is another event listener like onClick, but it appears now that it isn't actually real.

Comment: well that's correct, there's no onClientClick. react replicates most events that you have for the DOM, it's not configured to attach custom named events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React doesn't know what `onClientClick` is or what to do with it. If you are simply want to add additional `onClick` logic you can combine it with the existing `onClick` callback.

See [Synthetic Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)

And specifically [Mouse Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events)

> onClick onContextMenu onDoubleClick onDrag onDragEnd onDragEnter
> onDragExit onDragLeave onDragOver onDragStart onDrop onMouseDown
> onMouseEnter onMouseLeave onMouseMove onMouseOut onMouseOver onMouseUp

```
class Toolbar extends Component {

  // a bunch of functions
  
  changeColor = (event) =>{
    console.log("here")
  }

  // Define custom click handler to invoke both the passed
  // calculate callback and the changeColor callback
  clickHandler = event => {
    this.props.calculate(event);
    this.changeColor(event);
  }

  // more code

  <MyButton onClick={this.clickHandler}>
    Calculate
  </MyButton>

}
```